# Scala generics Confusion

Tags: java, scala, generics, parameterized-types

I have some generic/OOP Scala code (not useful, just classroom excercises)

I have a Container interface, "IterableContainer", that takes in and returns objects whose type is a subclass of AnyRef. It has a concrete sub-class that also takes in and returns objects whose type is a subclass of AnyRef.

```
  trait IterableContainer[Type <: AnyRef] {

    def length: Int

    def getAt(index: Int): Type

    def append(element: Type)
  }

  class IterableArrayList[T <: AnyRef]() extends IterableContainer[T] {

    val underlyingContainer = new ArrayBuffer[T](16)

    override def length: Int = {
      return underlyingContainer.length
    }

    override def getAt(index: Int): T =
    {
      if (index < underlyingContainer.length) {
        return underlyingContainer(index)
      } else {
        return null // Expression of type T does not conform to expected type. 
      }
    }

    override def append(element: T) = {
      underlyingContainer :+ element // :+ means append
    }
  }
```

Can anyone explain why I cannot return null when T is explicitly being stated as a an object of a type that extends AnyRef?

Also, if you understand Scala's generics better than I do, please explain further - they really make no sense to me (relative to C++ generics).

Comment: Just FYI, your use of `return` isn't very idiomatic. You can actually delete all the `return`s from your code, and it would still work (and it would be considered "better style").

Comment: Also, your `append` method currently has return-type `Unit`... Probably not what you want.

Comment: I didn't intend for the append method to return anything - just append something and return void (Unit). Also, when I did ":+" for append, it didn't actually append anything - the length of the ArrayBuffer stayed at zero.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. You should try using `+=` instead of `:+`. (`:+` returns a new collection rather than mutating the original.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `T <: AnyRef` does not imply that `T >: Null`.

I believe the only counter-example is `Nothing`.

Adding an additional (lower) type bound on your `IterableArrayList`'s type parameter makes the compiler happy:

```
class IterableArrayList[T >: Null <: AnyRef]() extends IterableContainer[T] {
```

Now the compiler knows that `T` is a subtype of `AnyRef` *and* a supertype of `Null`.

---

Now, you may be thinking to yourself, *"Doesn't this cause all sorts of problems for writing library code in Scala? People must have to add `T >: Null` everywhere!"*

However, the answer is no.

Why? Because Scala programmers pretty much never use `null`.

Let's look at `List` as an example. There are two ways to get the first element of a list:

`def head: A` [(scaladoc)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@head:A)

`def headOption: Option[A]` [(scaladoc)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@headOption:Option[A])

If you call `head` on an empty list, you get an exception. If you call `headOption` on an empty list, then you get `None`.

That's the usual strategy for Scala libraries: either you throw an exception, or you return an `Option` type—you never return `null`.

Example using `Option[T]`:

```
override def getAt(index: Int): Option[T] =
  if (index < underlyingContainer.length) {
    Some(underlyingContainer(index))
  } else {
    None
  }
```

Example using an exception:

```
override def getAt(index: Int): T = underlyingContainer(index)
```

Note that the underlying `ArrayBuffer` already throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is invalid. This also has the added advantage of working correctly if the user passes in a negative index... (You might want to add a `0 <= index` to your condition if you go with using `Option`.)

Comment: So I would either return Some[T] or None?

Comment: @MichaelLafayette - Yes, see the examples I added.